# What is a <versionspec> inspection error in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, request, pycharm, burp

Trying to build a program that uses a request file from a user.
When I try to parse that file named `POST.txt` I get an error:

```
<versionspec>, RequirementsTokenType.COMMENT, RequirementsTokenType.EOL, RequirementsTokenType.LSBRACE, RequirementsTokenType.SEMICOLON or RequirementsTokenType.WHITE_SPACE expected, got '/'
```

Looks like it interperts the request file as requirements file, but I have no idea why, I simply pasted a request from burpsuite and saved to a .txt file.
Until now, when I worked with requests files it worked well.

Here is the request:

```
POST /forum/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 31
Origin: http://localhost
DNT: 1
Connection: close
Referer: http://localhost/forum/
Cookie: PHPSESSID=f42ec9c38b762bb6f9856f5e99963610
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

l_username=l33t&l_password=1337
```

That's what my program looks like until now (Can't really move further if my request file is not parsed):

```
import argparse
import requests
import Burpee.burpee as burp
import re

MARKER = input("What are the markers for the variables (Default: '$'): ") or '$'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'sniper.py, Allows 1 set of payloads, runs by order '
                                               'in all the marked positions, one at a time.')
parser.add_argument('request_file', help = 'Request file with marked variables (POST or GET)')

args         = parser.parse_args()
request_file = args.request_file

headers, POST_data = burp.parse_request(request_file)
METHOD = burp.get_method_and_resource(request_file)[0]  # Sets METHOD (POST \ GET)

marked_vars = []
with open(request_file, 'r') as request_f:
    lines = request_f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        marked = re.findall('\$(.*?)\$', line)
        for var in marked:
            marked_vars.append(var)
    print(marked_vars)

destination = burp.get_method_and_resource(request_file)[1]  # Where the referer sends the request
```

And + the inspection error I get in PyCharm:

```
<versionspec>, RequirementsTokenType.COMMENT, RequirementsTokenType.EOL, RequirementsTokenType.LSBRACE, RequirementsTokenType.SEMICOLON or RequirementsTokenType.WHITE_SPACE expected, got '/'
```

Haven't seen this inspection in my life. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: PyCharm seems to be interpreting your file as a [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) - you may have misconfigured something.

Comment: The PyCharm inspection doesn't have anything to do with the exception you're getting, though. You've got some sort of bug. Post the whole exception output, including the full, unedited stack trace. Also, tell us what `Burpee` is.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica
It does look like it interprets the POST.txt as requirements but why...
The exception occurs after the file gets deleted, hence it doesn't matter.
The exception occurs because the file gets deleted that's why I get "list index out of range" because it tries to read from a file.
Burpee is module for parsing request file: [Burpee-GitHub](https://github.com/xscorp/Burpee)

Comment: Why are you opening this file in w+ mode?

Comment: lmao ye this should be 'r', my bad that's why it got deleted....

Comment: Ok i can work with the file now, though this inspection still bugs I wonder why it happens @user2357112supportsMonica

Comment: Seems you're using https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10837-requirements plugin, it has a bug processing txt files, reported issue https://github.com/meanmail-dev/requirements/issues/41

Comment: ok, how do i remove it?sorry for the noob question hehe @user2235698

Comment: @RobertTiger don't worry :) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-plugins.html#remove-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with a text file but apparently PyCharm doesn't recognize '.txt' extension.

Try creating a new file with no extension and then try to parse it.

It worked for me, so let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

To get Pycharm to stop complaining you have to right click the file and override the file type.

You will want to choose "Plain Text" - it will no longer provide syntax help.

[image: Shows the context menu for override file type]